# How do you hide a PowerShell parameter set?

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets

Say you have and old, deprecated parameter set, and a new parameter set:

```
SYNTAX
    Get-FooBar -SomeCommonParameter <string> -NewParameter <NewResourceType>

    Get-FooBar -SomeCommonParameter <string> -OldParameter <OldResourceType>
```

I want both parameter sets to continue working, to preserve compatibility with existing scripts, but I do not want the old deprecated parameter set to appear in the `Get-Help` output. Or, at the very least, clearly marked as deprecated within the `SYNTAX` section of `Get-Help`.

The `DontShow` property of the parameter attribute in PowerShell 4.0 helps a bit, as then IntelliSense/tab completion won't use it, but the parameter set still appears in the `Get-Help` output.

We are currently using PowerShell 3.0, but I don't think updating the version of PowerShell we target would be a blocker.

Comment: I don't think you can hide parameter sets. I'd put a deprecation notice in the `.NOTES` section.

Comment: You could also add something like `if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq $DeprecatedParameterSetName) { Write-Warning "The $DeprecatedParameterSetName parameter set has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release.  Please update your scripts." }`.

Answer (score 3):

Are you changing names, or is the functionality different as well? If you're just changing names, make the new name the name of the parameter and `alias` the old names.

If you're changing functionality as well, the `dbatools` module does the following:

- Indicate in the comment-based help that the parameter is deprecated (before describing the parameter)
- Tests for deprecated parameter names with an internal function, and provides the user with a warning message if they've used one.

Example:
[`Get-DbaDiskSpace`](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/functions/Get-DbaDiskSpace.ps1) calls [`Test-DbaDeprecation`](https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/dbatools/blob/master/internal/Test-DbaDeprecation.ps1) from its `begin` block. `Test-DbaDeprecation` parses the function call to find usage of the passed-in (deprecated) parameter name.